# How to get mongoDB database name from uri string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb native driver:

```
"mongodb": "^2.2.33",
```

And trying to retrieve the name of the database from uri...

I tried something like this:

```
const Mongodb = require('mongodb')
let mongoUrl = new Mongodb.create(opts.mongo.url);
console.log(mongoUrl.databaseName);
```

But not working, any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its part of the mongodb API

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animals', function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err
   console.log(db)
})
```

Comment: I am sorry ....could you share what does    **console.log(db)**  returns

Comment: there is a property in the pastebin json ->    **databaseName: 'test** is that required db name ?

Comment: glad...i could help :)

Comment: But how can I get it? :) I already do it like this: `db.s.databaseName` but I need to get it with function...

Comment: what does **console.log(db.s.databaseName)**   return ?  store it in a session

Comment: It returns database name

Answer (score 1):

With "mongodb": "3.3.3" driver, you can use mongoClient.s.options.dbName

Ideally, should have a getter.